# erratic touchpad on Toshiba Satellite laptop with 16.04

Tags: touchpad, 16.04, toshiba-satellite

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Toshiba Satellite Radius 12 laptop. Everything seems to be working except that the touchpad is very erratic. Two finger scroll generally works but moving the pointer more often than not is impossible. It jumps and freezes continually.

Running xinput, there are two touchpads listed:
TOSH120E:00 06CB:7CF7 Touchpad id=10 [slave pointer (2)]
SynPS/2 Synaptics Touchpad id=12 [slave pointer (2)]

Is it possible that there is a conflict between two separate drivers being loaded? And if so, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you search the internet for “Toshiba Radius Touchpad Not Working” you’ll see that a lot of people are having problems with that on other operating systems as well. It appears as if it’s a problem for that particular computer and not necessarily the OS that it is running.